# How to split a pdf file in columns with itext7 .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, itext

I need to export a gridview into a pdf file but i have to take advantage of space as much as possible because of hundreds of rows. To achieve this I need to split a page in columns, something like this

```
 |               Header                |

 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
 | A | B | C || A | B | C || A | B | C |
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-table-in-pdf-using-c-sharp-and-itextsharp

Comment: this shows how to only make a table but i guess it's a start, thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have asked for C# solution, I'll provied you with a Java one. Since the API is just the same, there should be no problem in porting the code to C#.

You have asked two questions actually:

1) How to enable n-column layout in iText7 (and n in your case equals to three)?
2) How to add a header to every page of the document?

Let's works by the numbers.

1) `ColumnDocumentRenderer` is responsible for that. You should just pass the areas which the columns are to occupy, and iText will do anything else by itself:

```
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4.rotate());

    Rectangle[] columns = {new Rectangle(36, 36, 250, 423),
            new Rectangle(36 + 250 + 10, 36, 250, 423),
            new Rectangle(36 + 250 + 250 + 20, 36, 250, 423)};
    document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
```

2) `IEventHandler`s are responsible for that. Ypou should just implement your header and handle it on some event (for example, on `PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE`):

```
    public class TableHeaderEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(docEvent.getPage(), new Rectangle(36, 36 + 423, 780, 100));
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("Header").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
    }
}

    TableHeaderEventHandler handler = new TableHeaderEventHandler();
    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, handler);
```

The example as a whole:

```
    @Test
public void threeColumnTableTest() throws IOException {
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(destinationFolder + "threeColumnTable.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4.rotate());
    Rectangle[] columns = {new Rectangle(36, 36, 250, 423),
            new Rectangle(36 + 250 + 10, 36, 250, 423),
            new Rectangle(36 + 250 + 250 + 20, 36, 250, 423)};
    document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));

    TableHeaderEventHandler handler = new TableHeaderEventHandler();
    pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, handler);


    Table table = new Table(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            table.addCell("row " + i + "column " + j);
        }
    }

    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}

public class TableHeaderEventHandler implements IEventHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(docEvent.getPage(), new Rectangle(36, 36 + 423, 780, 100));
        canvas.add(new Paragraph("Header").setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
    }
}
```

The resultant pdf:
[image]